# Kafka send to azure event hub

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I've set up a kafka in my machine and I'm trying to set up Mirror Maker to consume from a local topic and mirror it to an azure event hub, but so far i've been unable to do it and I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error when sending message to topic dev-eh-kafka-test with key: null, value: 5 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

After some time I realized that this must be the producer part so I tried to simply use the kafka-console-producer tool directly to event hub and got the same error.

Here is my producer settings file:

```
bootstrap.servers=dev-we-eh-feed.servicebus.windows.net:9093
compression.type=none
max.block.ms=0
# for event hub
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://dev-we-eh-feed.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=*****”;
```

Here is the command to spin the producer:

```
kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list dev-we-eh-feed.servicebus.windows.net:9093 --topic dev-eh-kafka-test
```

My event hub namespace has an event hub named dev-eh-kafka-test.

Has anyone been able to do it? Eventually the idea would be to SSL this with a certificate but first I need to be able to do the connection.

I tried using both Apacha Kafka 1.1.1 or the Confluent Kafka 4.1.3 (because this is the version the client is using).

==== UPDATE 1

Someone showed me how to get more logs and this seems to be the detailed version of the error

```
[2020-02-28 17:32:08,010] DEBUG [Producer clientId=console-producer] Initialize connection to node dev-we-eh-feed.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-02-28 17:32:08,010] DEBUG [Producer clientId=console-producer] Initiating connection to node dev-we-eh-feed.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-02-28 17:32:08,010] DEBUG [Producer clientId=console-producer] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 102400, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2020-02-28 17:32:08,010] DEBUG [Producer clientId=console-producer] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-02-28 17:32:08,010] DEBUG [Producer clientId=console-producer] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-02-28 17:32:08,010] DEBUG [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection with dev-we-eh-feed.servicebus.windows.net/51.144.238.23 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:124)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:93)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:235)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:196)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:559)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:495)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:424)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
[2020-02-28 17:32:08,010] DEBUG [Producer clientId=console-producer] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Comment: By the way, why not MirrorMaker2?

Comment: Can you `nc -vz dev-we-eh-feed.servicebus.windows.net 9093`? Are you sure that port is open and the address is correct?

Comment: @cricket_007, This is mandatory by the client, don't really have an option here.
I'm sure it reachable since i can telnet.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the configuration that worked (it seems I was missing client.id).

Also, it seems you can not choose the destination topic, it seems it must have the same name as the source...

```
bootstrap.servers=dev-we-eh-feed.servicebus.windows.net:9093
client.id=mirror_maker_producer
request.timeout.ms=60000
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://dev-we-eh-feed.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=******";
```

Comment: If you use MirrorMaker2, you can modify destination topic

Comment: Thank you for the info. unfortunately i'm stuck with this :(

Comment: How come? You should be able to separately download newer kafka versions/scripts without needing to upgrade kafka

Comment: Hi, @FEST Were you successful on sending data from local kafka to Azure event hub, Do you have some documentations to follow?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Is there any Sink Connector for kafka for Azure Eventhub, I need to send data from Kafka to Azure Eventhub.

Comment: EventHub uses Kafka protocol, so MirrorMaker should work @koiralo But you should make a separate issue rather than hijacking the comments

Comment: Hi @koiralo. I basically did what I have in here. Not much else.